# jQuery UI elements not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following kind of slider calculator which was not working.

[image]

Can't understand why I can't slide the bars here is the code.

```
<div style="widht: 700px;">
<table class="worksheet-table">
<tbody>
<tr><th>Estimated Years to Retirement</th>
<td>
<div id="years-to-retirement-caption" class="caption">20 years</div>
<div id="years-to-retirement-slider" class="slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">&nbsp;<a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="left: 19.1919%;"></a></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><th>Estimated Years in Retirement</th>
<td>
<div id="years-in-retirement-caption" class="caption">25 years</div>
<div id="years-in-retirement-slider" class="slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">&nbsp;<a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="left: 48.9796%;"></a></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><th>Desired Annual Income in Retirement<br> <em>(just think about it in today's dollars)</em></th>
<td>
<div id="desired-annual-income-caption" class="caption">$80,000</div>
<div id="desired-annual-income-slider" class="slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">&nbsp;<a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="left: 32%;"></a></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><th>Retirement Fund Needed</th>
<td>
<div id="retirement-fund-needed" class="caption">$2,000,000</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="worksheet-table">
<tbody>
<tr class="heading"><th colspan="2">Your Present Situation</th></tr>
<tr><th>Superannuation</th>
<td>
<div id="superannuation-caption" class="caption">$100,000</div>
<div id="superannuation-slider" class="slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">&nbsp;<a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="left: 10%;"></a></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><th>Savings (excluding home equity)</th>
<td>
<div id="savings-caption" class="caption">$10,000</div>
<div id="savings-slider" class="slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">&nbsp;<a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="left: 1%;"></a></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><th>Shares</th>
<td>
<div id="shares-caption" class="caption">$20,000</div>
<div id="shares-slider" class="slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">&nbsp;<a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="left: 2%;"></a></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><th>Equity Investment in Properties</th>
<td>
<div id="equity-caption" class="caption">$0</div>
<div id="equity-slider" class="slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">&nbsp;<a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="left: 0%;"></a></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><th>Other</th>
<td>
<div id="other-caption" class="caption">$0</div>
<div id="other-slider" class="slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">&nbsp;<a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="left: 0%;"></a></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><th>Today's Total Assets</th>
<td>
<div id="current-total-assets" class="caption">$130,000</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

The main page URL is http://www.insidewealth.com.au/calculate-your-retirement.html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you haven't called .slider() anywhere, but it's hard to say without posting code.

```
$("#years-to-retirement-slider").slider(); // etc
```

anywhere I assume.

There's also a typo here:

```
<div style="widht: 700px;">
```

width, not widht but that's beside the problem.

Comment: Can you please look at the view source for page http://www.insidewealth.com.au/calculate-your-retirement.html if there anything you can find from that? thanks a ton.

Comment: Well, it's rather hard to scrape but first make sure jQuery-UI is loaded (you can check it if $("#years-to-retirement-slider").slider() throws an error). If it isn't, load it on page load, then just do $(document).ready($("#years-to-retirement-slider").slider(); /* all the other ids until this last one*/ $("#other-slider").slider(););